# pdflatex work and latex not work

Tags: build-system

I am trying to understand the following problem: the "pdflatex main.tex" command runs successfully, but the "latex main.tex" command exits with error. Why does pdflatex work and latex not work? Please see the example below:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    Consider the sine function, whose graph is shown in figure (\ref{fig:figure1}).
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Figure_1.png}
        \caption{Sine(x) function.}
        \label{fig:figure1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}

% [terminal ~]$ latex main.tex
% LaTeX Error messages Line 7: 
% Cannot determine size of graphic in Figure_1.png (no BoundingBox).

% [terminal ~]$ pdflatex main.tex
% Successfully executed!
```

Comment: because latex can't handle png and pdf and jpg images, for this you need pdflatex.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I would delete the question. It is not a good question as you didn't provide any details like a minimal example or the exact log error, I could only answer by using my rather good crystal ball.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Wow! Let's correct the bad-formulated question then.